# Parallelization of MATLink

Tags: parallelization

I am attempting to parallelize the construction of a table using `MATLink` and `ParallelTable`.

Let's consider a sample `MATLAB` function defined by

```matlab
    function [out1,out2] = TestFunction(in1,in2,in3)
    %TestFunction Example function
    out1=in1;
    out2=in2+in3;
    end
```

Consider the non-parallel construction of the table

```
    Needs["MATLink`"];
    OpenMATLAB[];
    TestFunction = MFunction["TestFunction", "OutputArguments" -> 2];
    tab = Table[
       {out1, out2} = TestFunction[i, 2 i, 3 i];
       {out1, out2}
       , {i, 1, 3}];
```

Which yields the output

```
   {{1.,5.},{2.,10.},{3.,15.}}
```

My attempt to parallelize the construction is as follows:

First, launch kernels and load MATLink:

```
   LaunchKernels[];
   ParallelNeeds["MATLink`"];
   ParallelEvaluate[
      OpenMATLAB[];
      TestFunction = MFunction["TestFunction", "OutputArguments" -> 2];
    ];
```

Which yields the following two errors for each of the kernels

```
   Global`OpenMATLAB::shdw :  Symbol OpenMATLAB appears in multiple contexts   {Global`,MATLink`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
   Global`MFunction::shdw :  Symbol MFunction appears in multiple contexts {Global`,MATLink`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
```

and MATLAB is not opened on any kernals. 
As a result, the parallel table construction

```
   tab = ParallelTable[
      {out1, out2} = TestFunction[i, 2 i, 3 i];
      {out1, out2}
      , {i, 1, 3}];
```

yields the error

```
Set::shape :  Lists {out1,out2} and Global`MFunction[TestFunction,OutputArguments->2][1,2,3] are not the same shape.
```

for each kernel. No output is generated.

What is the correct way to use `MATLink` on multiple kernels?

**Additional details:**

The output of `FindFile["Matlink`"]` is

```
   In[1]:=FindFile["MATLink`"]
   Out[1]=C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\MATLink\Kernel\init.m
```

The output of `ParallelEvaluate[FindFile["MATLINK`"]` is

```
   In[2]:=ParallelEvaluate[FindFile["MATLink`"]]
   Out[2]={C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\MATLink\Kernel\init.m,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\MATLink\Kernel\init.m,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\MATLink\Kernel\init.m,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\MATLink\Kernel\init.m}
```

The output of `$Path` is

```
   In[3]:= $Path
   Out[3]= {C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Applications,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Links,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Kernel,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Autoload,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications,
   C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Kernel,
   C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Autoload,
   C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications,
   .,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Packages,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Autoload,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Autoload,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Applications,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\ExtraPackages,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Kernel\Packages,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\Documentation\English\System,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Data\ICC}
```

The output of `First@ParallelEvaluate[$Path]` is

```
   In[4]:= First@ParallelEvaluate[$Path]
   Out[4]= {C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Links,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Kernel,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Autoload,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications,
   C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Kernel,
   C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Autoload,
   C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications,
   .,
   C:\Users\VHYDAN001,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Packages,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Autoload,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Autoload,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\Applications,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\AddOns\ExtraPackages,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Kernel\Packages,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\Documentation\English\System,
   C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.1\SystemFiles\Data\ICC}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is a new MATLAB instance opened for each parallel Mathematica kernel? Isn't licensing an issue?

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I want to open a new MATLAB instance for each parallel kernel but I am struggling to do so. If I'm just using MATLAB (without MATLink or Mathematica) I am able to open multiple instances of MATLAB. Further, if I open more than one instance of Mathematica I am able to open MATLAB from each instance and I can run the non-parallel code calling the MATLAB function from each instance of Mathematica simultaneously. So I don't think licensing is an issue.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino No, the `Global` context makes it clear that the package was never loaded on subkernels. I will be EXTREMELY surprised if the situation is not what I described in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package was loaded on the subkernels, but not the main kernel. [`ParallelNeeds`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelNeeds.html) only loads it on the subkernels. You must also use `Needs`.

What happened is that since the package wasn't loaded on the main kernel, the symbol `OpenMATLAB` was interpreted by the main kernel as `` Global`OpenMATLAB ``, not has `` MATLink`OpenMATLAB ``. It sent the `` Global` `` version to the subkernels, which then issued a warning about multiple symbols with the same name in different contexts.

Please try like this:

```
LaunchKernels[];
Needs["MATLink`"];
ParallelNeeds["MATLink`"];   
ParallelEvaluate[
   OpenMATLAB[];
   TestFunction = MFunction["TestFunction", "OutputArguments" -> 2];
];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not well today and can't show you how to effectively set the path on parallel kernels. For now just use `ParallelEvaluate` to change `$Path`.

Comment: Executing `ParallelEvaluate[Print@FindFile["MATLink"]]` yields a path that is not on the `$Path` for the parallel kernels. However, it also isn't on the regular `$Path` and for non parallel computations I am able to use MATLink. Adding the path to each kernel does eliminate the first error messages, but I am still unable to open MATLAB using `ParallelNeeds["MATLink`"]; `ParallelEvaluate[ OpenMATLAB[]; TestFunction = MFunction["TestFunction", "OutputArguments" -> 2];];`

Comment: @DvanHuyssteen There are some misunderstandings here. What you say cannot possibly be true, at least the way I understand it. So, please edit into your answer the output from: ``FindFile["MATLink`"]``, ``ParallelEvaluate[FindFile["MATLink`"]]``, `$Path`, `First@ParallelEvaluate[$Path]`. Evaluate these (and nothing else!) as the first four commands immediately after kernel startup.

Comment: I have added these outputs to the original question under the **Additional Details** section.

Comment: @DvanHuyssteen Thanks for posting the results. You say "Which yields the following two errors **for each of the kernels**". Actually this looks like you did not load MATLink on the main kernel before trying to use it on subkernels. You have the `ParallelNeeds`, but you are missing the `Needs`. Make sure you use *both* `Needs` and `ParallelNeeds`. Let me know if this was the problem.

Comment: That was indeed the problem! Thanks a lot!